# Disable Safari Extensions

Tags: safari, safari-extension

Is there a way to disable safari extensions for a specific domain? Like my development domain? And still have the extensions working for the rest of the web?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your development domain's URL to the extension's Blacklist in the Extension Builder?

Comment: I want disable all!!! Like Apple's extension gallery does. Or, at least, keep it disabled in Webkit while using it in Safari.